# Could I find a variable in the bessel function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am using Python to solve an equation. I added the 'Bessel function' in scipy.special, It was working. Now I want to find a variable using Bessel function. For example, I added the `order(1)` and `value(0.44005058574)` in Python, but it is not working. (in order to find the variable, I also used `solver`)

How I can solve the problem?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sc
import math
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import solve

x=Symbol('x')
y=sc.jn(1,x)-0.44005058574
print(solve(x))
```

Comment: Does this file as you've written not work? What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

As the output is hinting, the function `scipy.special.jn` does not know how to handle the object `x` from `simpy`. Instead, you should use a numerical approach

```
>>> from scipy import optimize
>>> f = lambda x: sc.jn(1, x) - 0.44005058574
>>> root = optimize.newton(f, 1.0)
>>> print(root)
0.9999999999848267
```